# There are no Stack Exchange sites that allow asking for "OpenSource Library Recommendations", shouldn't we make one?

Tags: discussion

**Stack Overflow** is defined to ask *specific* programming questions, with code, and a specific problem.

**Code Review** is defined to look through code that is actually working, by professionals. It's actually a *really* useful website, and I love it!

**Programmers** is defined to discuss conceptual problems (which, by the way, used to be part of Stack Overflow, and you can find quite lengthy and insightful from back in 2009-2010 under *community wiki* answers). Of course, problem with Programmers is that it's fairly unknown compared to SO, and therefore has less visitors, and possibly less valuable input from people experienced in the field. Which is why some of their on-topic questions end up on SO in the first place.

**Software Recommenders** is defined for *specific* type of recommendations. I personally don't really think even they know what they're looking for, though. (although to be honest, I'm just angry at them for locking [my question on essential Android libraries](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19563/5288) as too broad, although I guess I could have added more information on what each library does - but it wouldn't have helped.)

---

What bugs me is that there is *no stack exchange site* that allows questions like these:

[What modern C libraries should be in my toolbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777764/what-modern-c-libraries-should-be-in-my-toolbox)

[JavaScript Chart Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library)

Clearly these questions have a *huge* number of favorites, a lot of votes, there is a *demand* for these kinds of questions, but each of them are locked for the following reason:

```
"Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, 
library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic 
for Stack Overflow as they tend to 
attract opinionated answers and spam. 
Instead, describe the problem 
and what has been done so far to solve it."
```

and more commonly,

```
locked

This question exists because 
it has historical significance, 
but it is not considered a good, 
on-topic question for this site, 
so please do not use it as evidence 
that you can ask similar questions here. 
This question and its answers are frozen 
and cannot be changed.
```

I **do** see why these are not relevant on SO, but I **don't see an alternative site for this type of question**, even though the vote counts clearly indicate that it would be useful. As long as instead of just saying "you should use MigLayout", it would include what problem it solves, and some example code on the basics; or at least what it's responsible for. I think we should have a **site** *dedicated to* **OpenSource Library Recommendations**.

Yay? Nay? Is this even a bad question for Meta? I don't think this is a bad question, I did look into [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), but I'm still brainstorming and `pair programming` exists for a similar reason, and thus request assistance in figuring this out.

Comment: There's forums everywhere on the internet where you can build lists of whatever you want. Questions that can be answered with everyone's favorite _foo_ are plain useless, become outdated real fast, spam nests, etc. Pointless. Search engines are great for giving you lists of stuff already.

Comment: What about the existing [SE Software Revommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the questions I linked as examples would still be deemed as "off-topic" or "too broad".

Comment: @Mat isn't that the point of the Community Wiki to keep them up to date?

Comment: @Mat that, and "there's forums everywhere" is not specific. I personally haven't found any other than Reddit, otherwise it's pretty much "blogspot" or "wordpress" sites stating `these are what I found and they are great`, but it cannot be updated by the community and keep it up to date...

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: "these are what I found and they are great" is what you'll get _anywhere_ where you post such vague, broad questions that don't have any sort of focus. "What can I put in my toolbox"? "What libs for Android"? _Anything_ that's a lib for Android is fair game for your question. "Essential" doesn't narrow it down at all - if someone wrote it, they'll probably find it essential. Focus on problems you're trying to solve. Packing your toolbox with the largest amount of shiny tools doesn't make a good toolbox.

Comment: @Mat reasonable point, but I'll attempt to counter it by saying that for that, you need to know that you have a specific *need* in the first place. Some people can make messy horrible code, and seeing a library in action or a concept in practice could help them realize possibilities on how to make it better. For example, until I had to develop using Spring Framework, I didn't even **think** about wanting to use Dependency Injection in Android. Now I'm not even sure what I'd do without it, and I look back on previous code with dread.

Comment: I believe that seeing that a library solves a problem shows that the problem existed in the first place. You can't fix problems that you don't notice, which is why I think sometimes seeing examples of it in practice is useful.

Comment: I'm not a Java or Android developer at all, but even I have heard about Spring a million times simply through ambient noise. If there's such a popular and obvious library, anyone who thinks of searching for any library is pretty sure to very quickly come across it any way they'd search for it. I don't see a good argument for needing a list. You just need to be aware that you should stick your head out a bit. This need doesn't change whether there is a list or not.

Comment: @deceze well yes, but Spring does many things. **Dependency Injection** was the concept as an example. Right now, the "fad" library is *RxJava*, and I'm not sure what the problem is that it solves. There isn't really a place to ask it either. Oh well.

Comment: @Epic Sounds like you're just discovering essential concepts and would have liked to know about those sooner. Well, there's no fix for that, and a list of libraries won't help you there either. You will simply have to build up that kind of knowledge over time, and you need to keep reading about a variety of topics to even discover what you need to learn. You cannot really summarise all that in a list. There's way too much stuff that you need to learn about than a single list can hold.

Comment: @deceze *sigh* I guess you're right.

Comment: Your specific question on Android seemed more like you pimping those libraries than really asking a question.  I'd close it too.  The idea is to recommend software for a specific purpose, asking "name your favorite libraries" is a bad question with too broad of scope.  (As a side note-  you really think Butterknife is good?  It makes your code more obscure, more complex, less performant, and provides no benefit. Its a horrible idea.  Using that should require all your fingers to be broken so you can never program again)

Comment: @GabeSechan I literally use it only for the `@InjectView` and `@OnClick(R.id.button)` annotations, because the `(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button); button.setOnClickListener(...)` is way too long, it gets a `View` parameter, and is just a convoluted mess. Saves me the trouble of refactoring the anonymous listeners into their own methods. That, and ButterKnife uses annotation processing, not reflection, so the performance difference should be negligible. But yes, I'm curious to know what current devs "pimp" as libraries, and I'm not sure what the right platform is for that.

Comment: @GabeSechan but I'm curious to hear of any cases where ButterKnife did make things go bad, and why one shouldn't use it :D That's the whole point of learning, isn't it?

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: @gnat I see. So libraries should have been in the scope of NPR, I guess?

Comment: "NPR was supposed to be a site where questions that were too subjective / broad for Stack Overflow would find a new home... NPR would host all those exciting and sometimes helpful (but not really _answerable_) questions..."

Comment: @gnat thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bigger problem with creating such a centrally maintained list is that is creates a gatekeeper. Sure, you can ask such a question today and come up with a list by some user which may even be a decent recommendation *today*. But if this list fulfils its purpose and does become the canonical reference list for library recommendations, then how is the state of the art going to evolve? There will be new libraries coming, libraries on that list will age and fall out of favour, things will change. Who will maintain that list? Who will decide which new libraries get on the list and which will be taken off?

That list will simply grow stale and become worthless after a while, *or* it will grow to encompass all possible libraries ever and thereby grow useless, *or* it will become a holy resource with a holy gatekeeper who gets to decide which libraries are deemed popular and worthwhile and which aren't. Keeping such a list in sync with reality over a long period of time is virtually impossible.

This is the same issue on SE, or on a blog post, or in a forum post, or anywhere really.

The best, most realistic way is to keep this decentralised. Look at the most popular packages on Github or other open source repositories, keep reading new blog articles by influential technologists, keep your finger on the pulse of technology by picking up new trending libraries from discussions in forums (and/or here on SO). That's the way to filter out good, up-to-date, popular libraries in a decentralised and "democratic" fashion. Not lists.

Comment: While I agree in principle, it is also (somewhat) true that answers on Stack Overflow (and elsewhere in the Stack, I suppose) will also become outdated over time.  As technologies evolve, a lot is certainly baked into a language to solve common problems.